# update array of object in array of object in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have data in react like this one :

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([
  {
    "q_id": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "",
    "options": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "answer_id": 1,
        "text": "",
        "is_answer": false
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "answer_id": 1,
        "text": "",
        "is_answer": false
      }
    ]
  },
 {
    "q_id": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "",
    "options": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "answer_id": 1,
        "text": "",
        "is_answer": false
      },
    ]
  }
])
```

I need to search the first array and find the options then find the object inside options after that I wanna update the "text" inside options with the user input. how can do that?

Comment: can you give an example? I am little bit confused about `search the first array`

Answer (score 0):

As react states are immutable changing value inside data object won't trigger render. You have to update state after modifying the data.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([ { ..object1.. }, { ..object2.. } ]);

// for updating
data[0].options[0].text = 'your value change'; // this is first object, object1 and options1
setData(data); // this will trigger update
```

Comment: but there is one problem it changes just one letter.
if I type  "h" it save it but I start to add more it replace the word

Answer (score 0):

This will update the text value, the indexes will have to be adjusted if you want to target other values

```
setData((data) => {
      data[0].options[0].text = "new value";
      return data;
    });
```

Comment: but there is one problem it changes just one letter.
if I type  "h" it save it but I start to add more it replace the word